# Elements on Mint localhost Template Kits returning: unexpected error from API call

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, api, elementor

Hi Everybody Good Day!

I download the **Elementor** and **Envato Elements** plugins into my **localhost** linux mint wordpress.
I set up permalinks and everything else on wordpress as normal, then I started to check for Template Kits from Elements, the plugin worked for about 3 minutes while I was deciding for template kits, then it stooped and start to give the following message:

**Unexpected Error
Sorry there was an unexpected error from API call:*
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="
```

Refreshing the Page, Clearing Cache, Deactivating and Reactivating Plugins, Deleting and Installing again, Restarting, Uninstalling and Reinstalling the Xampp, waiting for a few hours, or even turning ON and OFF the laptop (all steps) several times did not make any difference.

The Debug Details shows the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>

<title>Object not found!</title>

<link rev="made" href="mailto:you@example.com" />

<style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/

body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }

a:link { color: #0000CC; }

p, address {margin-left: 3em;}

span {font-size: smaller;}

/*]]>*/--></style>

</head>


<body>

<h1>Object not found!</h1>

<p>



The requested URL was not found on this server.


The link on the

<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php%3fpage=envato-elements">referring

page</a> seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of

<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php%3fpage=envato-elements">that page</a>

about the error.


</p>

<p>

If you think this is a server error, please contact

the <a href="mailto:you@example.com">webmaster</a>.


</p>


<h2>Error 404</h2>

<address>

<a href="/">localhost</a><br />

<span>Apache/2.4.43 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3</span>

</address>

</body>

</html>
```

So I've been reading all your documentation and checking online all available information, but unfortunately, I don't have much experience on coding and I've not been able to find the cause of the problem (even if it is under my nose), so i would like to ask for someone to assist me  to find the solution to this error.

I look forward for your assistance and since now I appreciate you guys attention.
Best Regards
Pedro Godoi

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. But this error can be produced because of missing zip extensions. Enable zip extension for php to remove this error .